# How can I add a dynamic, application specific quicklist for recently used files to the Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, libreoffice, .desktop, quicklists

It would be an awesome feature to access recently used documents from LibreOffice with a dynamic quicklist in the launcher. There is [quite some experience on how to create custom *static* quicklists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available/41228#41228).

But is anyone out there who might give some constructive orientation on how to build a *dynamic* quicklist for recently used docs in lo?

The Ubuntu wiki has a [very brief description](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Dynamic_Quicklist_entries) on how to create quicklists with python or vala. I am not experienced in either of the two and I did not find comprehensive example scripts for dynamic quicklists out there. Therefore I'm looking for some easier way to implement it or somebody who has already done/seen it.

Comment: Interesting, could be done, but would still need additional stuff (background script) to update the quicklist, which would make it *a lot* simpler to just add a "dynamic" static section with a separator in between.  Would the technique bother you? (updating the quicklist with a background script). The result would be the same.

Comment: Related/duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/39376/367990

Comment: @ByteCommander. I saw the question that you marked as a possible duplicate before but it is not really the same. Whereas the former question asks if it has already been implemented and the answer is simply "no", my question regards on how to implement it anyway in an easy way.

Comment: @JacobVlijm . I would not mind if a background script updates the quicklist. I was thinking of a similar approach by adding a static section which is parsing information from the document where libreoffice stores the recently used documents (no idea where that might be). like that you would not even need a background script...

Comment: I did not really flag it as duplicate because I saw that the other answers were simply "no". Just wanted to show you the link. It's indeed more "related" than "duplicate".

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks! you' re the best, that gives the chance to get it working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adding a dynamic "recently used" section to the launcher of an application

The *full* integration of an application with the mentioned *dynamic quicklist* -entries most likely needs to be done *from inside* of the application. After all, the most direct information on used files comes from the application itself.

However, since editing the source code is outside the scope of what we're doing, that would not be the road to take.

*Then what?*

That doesn't mean we cannot achieve pretty much exactly the same result, maybe even in a more flexible and general way, from "outside". All the information we need is available in the dynamically updated file: `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`, from which we can retrieve the complete history of opened files, the corresponding date & time information and the application that was used.

Furthermore, to add a *dynamically* updated section to a launcher can very well be done as part of the "traditional" (static) section. The key of the solution is then to create a process that takes care of the above actions without adding a noticeable burden to your system.
As mentioned in [the link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Dynamic_Quicklist_entries) from the question, *some* background process would be needed anyway to keep track of the changes and pass the instructions.

The script below is pretty much doing exactly that.

#### The solution; a background script

The values in the script below are specifically set for `LibreOffice` and its documents. Without any editing, it can be used to add a *recently used* -section to the `LibreOffice-Writer`launcher. It will show the last 10 used documents, opened by any of the `LibreOffice` -modules.

The solution can however be used to add a "recently used" section to *many* applicatiosn with a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`. Since the file `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` is `Gtk` related, most likely, applications with a `Gtk` window will be our potential candidates (that is, if the application opens and edits files). Furthermore, the number of files to show is arbitrary.

#### How it looks

The solution adds a section to the targeted launcher in the Unity launcher, showing an arbitrary number of recently used files, e.g.:

- show the last seven files:

  [image]
- or the last ten files:

  [image]
- With the same ease however, we can give the `gedit` launcher a dynamic section, showing the last seven files, opened with `gedit` (see image further below)

#### How to use

*Assuming you have LibreOffice preinstalled (the downloaded version does not have a referring `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` which is needed by the script, but somewhere else, please mention if you need to setup the separately downloaded LO version)*

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `dynamic_recent.py`
   For `LibreOffice`, the process name is `soffice`, already set correctly in the script.

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import os
   import time
   import shutil

   # --- set the number of docs to show in recently used
   n = 7
   # --- set the process name of the targeted application
   application = "soffice"
   #--- ONLY change the value below into "xdg-open" if you do not use LO preinstalled
   #    else the value should be the same as in application = (above)
   open_cmd = "soffice"
   # --- set the targeted .desktop file (e.g. "gedit.desktop")
   target = "libreoffice-writer.desktop"

   # --- don't change anything below
   home = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.local/share"
   loc = home+"/applications/"+target
   recdata = home+"/recently-used.xbel"

   def runs(app):
       try:
           # see if the application is running
           app = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", app]).decode("utf-8")
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           return False
       else:
           return True

   def get_lines():
       # retrieve information from the records:
       # -> get bookmark line *if* the application is in the exec= line
       with open(recdata) as infile:
           db = []
           for l in infile:
               if '<bookmark href="file://' in l:
                   sub = l
               elif 'exec="&apos;'+application in l:
                   db.append(sub)
       # fix bug in xbel -file in 15.04
       relevant = [l.split('="') for l in set(db) if all([not "/tmp" in l, "." in l])]
       relevant = [[it[1][7:-7], it[-2][:-10]] for it in relevant]
       relevant.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
       return [item[0].replace("%20", " ") for item in relevant[::-1][:n]]

   def create_section(line):
       # create shortcut section
       name = line.split("/")[-1]
       return [[
           "[Desktop Action "+name+"]",
           "Name="+name,
           "Exec="+open_cmd+" '"+line+"'",
           "\n",
           ], name]

   def setup_dirs():
       # copy the global .desktop file to /usr/share/applications/
       glo = "/usr/share/applications/"+target
       if not os.path.exists(loc):
           shutil.copy(glo,loc)

   def edit_launcher(newdyn, target, actionlist):
       # read the current .desktop file
       ql = [list(item) for item in list(enumerate(open(loc).read().splitlines()))]
       # find the Actions= line
       currlinks = [l for l in ql if "Actions=" in l[1]]
       # split the line (if it exists)  by the divider as delimiter 
       linkline = currlinks[0][1].split("divider1")[0] if currlinks else None
       # define the shortcut sections, belonging to the dynamic section (below the divider)
       lowersection = [l for l in ql if "[Desktop Action divider1]" in l]
       # compose the new Actions= line
       addlinks = (";").join(actionlist) + ";"
       if linkline:
           newlinks = linkline + addlinks
           ql[currlinks[0][0]][1] = newlinks
           # get rid of the "dynamic" section  
           ql = ql[:lowersection[0][0]] if lowersection else ql
           # define the new file
           ql = [it[1] for it in ql]+newdyn
           with open(loc, "wt") as out:
               for l in ql:
                   out.write(l+"\n")
       else:
           newlinks = "Acrions="+addlinks

   setup_dirs()
   lines1 = []

   while True:
       time.sleep(2)
       # if the application does not run, no need for a check of .xbel
       if runs(application):
           lines2 = get_lines()
           # (only) if the list of recently used changed: edit the quicklist
           if lines1 != lines2:
               actionlist = ["divider1"]
               newdyn = [
                   "[Desktop Action divider1]",
                   "Name=" + 37*".",
                   "\n",
                   ]
               for line in lines2:
                   data = create_section(line)
                   actionlist.append(data[1])
                   section = data[0]
                   for l in section:
                       newdyn.append(l)
               edit_launcher(newdyn, target, actionlist)           
           lines1 = lines2
   ```
2. In the head section of the script, you can set a number of options:

   ```py
   # --- set the number of docs to show in recently used
   n = 7
   # --- set the process name of the targeted application
   application = "soffice"
   #--- ONLY change the value below into "xdg-open" if you do not use LO preinstalled
   #    else the value should be the same as in application = (above)
   open_cmd = "soffice"
   # --- set the targeted .desktop file (e.g. "gedit.desktop")
   target = "libreoffice-writer.desktop"
   ```

   Most of the options speak for themselves, if you want to add the dynamic section to the `LO-Writer` launcher, leave everything as it is. If not, set the appropriate launcher.
3. Test- run the script by running from a terminal:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/dynamic_recent.py
   ```
4. The script copied the global `.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications` (in this case `~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop`). Drag the local copy to the launcher (else you'd need to log out/in).
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/dynamic_recent.py
   ```

#### To use it on other applications

As mentioned, you can easily use the script to add a dynamic "recently used" section to other application's launcher(s). To do so, see the `gedit` example setting for the head section of the script:

```py
# --- set the number of docs to show in recently used
n = 7
# --- set the process name of the targeted application
application = "gedit"
#--- ONLY change the value below into "xdg-open" if you do not use LO preinstalled
#    else the value should be the same as in application = (above)
open_cmd = "gedit"
# --- set the targeted .desktop file (e.g. "gedit.desktop")
target = "gedit.desktop"
```

[image]

#### How it works

- The script periodically looks through the file `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` to find matching files, opened with `LibreOffice` (processname: `soffice`)

  It uses a pretty fast algorithm to do so, "shooting" through the file in a single pass, to retrieve the needed lines (two per "record"). The result is that the script is very low on juice.
- Once the relevant lines are retrieved from the file, the lines are sorted by date/time, creating a "top ten" (or any other number) of most recently used files of the corresponding application.
- *ONLY* if this list is changed, the `.desktop` file is updated.

I could notice nor measure any additional load to my system, running the script in the background.

Tested on 14.04 / 15.10

#### How to restore the original launcher

Simply remove the local copy of the launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`

#### Notes

- In case you use [Unity Quicklist Editor](https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/qle) to edit your launchers (quicklists), you should avoid editing launchers  with a dynamically updated "last used" -section from this answer. The edits you make with the QUicklist Editor will instantly be overwritten by the script.
- You can edit your quicklist manually, but make sure you add new item *before* (on the left side of) `divider1` in the `Actions=` - line

  `Actions=Window;Document;`**divider1**`;aap.sh;Todo;pscript_2.py;currdate;bulkmail_llJacob;verhaal;test doc;`

  All items *on the right* of `divider1` belong to the dynamically updated section.

---

### Major edit

Some major improvements were just made:

1. The script now *only* checks the `.xbel` file while the targeted application runs (since there won't be changes on the recently used list if the application does not run). The script already was low on juice, but now, only keeping an eye on if the application runs, means even less to your system.
2. In 15.04+, it turns out the `.xbel` file had double mentions of new files; one with, and one without extension. The effect of that is now eliminated.

---

Comment: Wow I'm impressed!! I encountered one issue using it so far (doubled entries for newly created LO documents). Also I would like to change the script in order to use more applications from "/usr/share/applications" where most of my applications are stored... would you like to continue discussion here or would it be better to move it to launchpad?

Comment: @joaoal I love this project, think it is worth moving it to launchpad, since it might be useful for a broader range of situations *and* I' d very much like to improve it, make it work for multiple applications at once (which should not be too difficult). This was the first shot. I Think I will rewrite it from scratch. The double mentions I had only once, with a specific file, not after that any more. Something I have to look into. If you'd like to join me on launchpad, would be great.

Comment: @joaoal I fixed the Double mentions. It was most likely caused by a small bug in the file `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`, not cleaning up double records in some situations.

Comment: I'd be happy to assist you with testing and bug-reports where I can if you move it to Launchpad. just paste the link and I'll continue toying around with the script. One think that might be worth checking for several situations is whether all programs recently used docs get stored into the xbel file. With a quick lock I had the impression that it was just a couple of them.

Comment: Since `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` is `GTK+`  related (the file exists on Windows too), you would expect at least all Gtk GUI applications would appear in the file (if the application edits files that is). Are you missing applications?

Comment: yeah was a bug. After deactivating the option in user settings and reactivating it it now works without harm. I already deleted both comments. sorry for that.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Very nice answer. May I ask how you managed to make a screenshot of the quicklists? I recently failed to do that - it always collapses when I try to shoot them.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks! :) The screenshot, I take with good old gnome-screenshot, the "all screen" -option with a delay of 4 seconds, then cropped afterwards.

Comment: @joaoal please check the latest version, it has some important improvements.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Works like a charm for openoffice. did not get it to work with qgis. did you put it to launchpad?

Comment: @joaoal It certainly will not work with all applications (is that still in my answer? will edit). It is not yet on Launchpad. Need to make a gui. I found a way to make it work for multiple applications, but need a rewrite...\

Comment: @JacobVlijm All right! Take your time. It is already amazing and I am sure it will get a lot of attention when rewritten. Let me know if you need any support. thanks so far!

Comment: @JacobVlijm Have you been able to advance on this tool? I use it everyday with libreoffice! would love to see this ongoing!

Comment: @joaoal I love to hear that! After summer, I plan to work on a merged one with this: http://askubuntu.com/a/804533/72216. Will move it to launchpad... I will let you know when it is "launched".

Comment: @JacobVlijm Great!!!!! :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes. Getting similar feature from that indicator would be great. Btw, is this yours http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/add-recently-accessed-files-as.html ?